# Python 3D array. Calculate R squared

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have 2 ndarrays with 3 dimensions. I need to calculate the Rsquared over these ndarrays. To clarify.

```
Array1.shape = Array2.shape = (100, 100, 10)
```

So...

```
resultArray = np.ones(100*100).reshape(100,100)

for i in range(Array1.shape[0]:
    for j in range(Array1.shape[1]: 
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.stats.linregress(Array1[i:i+1,j:j+1,:],Array1[i:i+1,j:j+1,:])
        R2 = r_value**2
        result[ i , j ] = R2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If passed two arrays, `stats.linregress` expects the two arrays to be 1-dimensional.

`Array1[i:i+1,j:j+1,:]` has shape `(1, 1, 10)`, so it is 3-dimensional. So instead use `Array1[i, j, :]`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

Array1 = np.random.random((100, 100, 10))
Array2 = np.random.random((100, 100, 10))
resultArray = np.ones(100*100).reshape(100,100)
for i in range(Array1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(Array1.shape[1]):
            slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(
                Array1[i, j, :],
                Array1[i, j, :])
            R2 = r_value**2
            resultArray[ i , j ] = R2

print(resultArray)
```

Comment: Thank you unutbu. The way that I've wrote works, my input data was wrong, but I'll keep your suggestion, since your code is cleaner than mine.

Comment: @wfoschiera don't forget you can accept the answer clicking on the arrow at the left-hand side if you want...

Comment: Thank you Saullo. 
So, I'm still haven a problem with the time to process all my data. I'm talking about more than 6000 arrays with shape (800,870,10) generally. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: @wfoschiera: NumPy confers a speed advantage when you off-load a lot of calculations in *one* NumPy function call. Here, you are calling `linregress` on tiny arrays of length 10 hundreds of thousands, or perhaps millions of times. That's a recipe for slowness. I don't see an obvious way to gain a speed advantage using NumPy, since I don't see a way to pack the work done by many calls to linregress into one call. However, if you post another question showing your code (with all the pairs of 6000 arrays), perhaps someone will have a suggestion for you.

Comment: @unutbu: Thank you again, but is more complex than that. Now, I'm trying to write a function to calculate just the R-squared, that I believe is clever than the actually code. I'm working with Modis data (a sensor onboard Terra and Aqua platforms), to extract some statistics from a period of 10 years. I'll try to think in a different way, if runs faster than now, I'll post here.